# Trouble using index in ArabicAnalyzer using lucene

Tags: java, lucene, arabic

I have a problem with the ArabicAnalyzer in lucene. When I run the indexing I think that it works successfully, but when I run the search for a word in Arabic, there is no match found in the index.

I have already set the text file encoding in the project property to UTF-8.

Do I have to change something in the scanning or the string and if yes how can I do it?

```
QueryParser parser = new QueryParser(Version.LUCENE_30,
                       "contents", new ArabicAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_30));
```

Comment: Have you opened the index in Luke to see what's actually there? Luke is a good tool for debugging indexing and query operations.

Comment: Could you give some example of arabic text that is indexed AND some arabic search query? Second, did you update Lucene to version 4 or 5 in the meantime and tried again?